# how launch PSQL if many versions of postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have **ubuntu 18.04 x64** on which i installed **PostgreSQL10** and **PostgreSQL9.6**

When type **psql**, i have psql for PostgreSQL10.

**How to launch psql for PostgreSQL9.6 ?**

At finish, i would like to set up PGadmin 3 for those two postgresql instances

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `psql` in version 9.6 for a PostgreSQL 9.6 server. The clients are always downwards compatible.

Best practice is, to use always the latest client, no matter what version of server you are running.